# jQuery fade out adding a class to id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have scenario where loader and video fade in and out. On fade out of '#tout' I want to add a class to also fade out '.loader-box'. what the best way to add a class to the scenario. I have tried with below code but not having success, any suggestion/solution would be very helpful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vid-delay").delay(2500).fadeIn(300);
    $("#vid_box") delay(2500).fadeIn(300);
});
$("#nav-toggle") click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-active')
});


$("#tout").delay(2800).fadeOut();
$(".loader-box").delay(2800).fadeOut();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you miss some dots , fix your code and try again.

Comment: can you add your html part ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `.addClass()` function with `fadeIn()` like following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
  $("#tout").delay(2800).fadeOut().addClass("loader-box");
  
  $(".loader-box").delay(2800).fadeOut();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tout">this will fade out</div>
```

Comment: #tout and loader-box both need to fade out

Comment: @Olivbelle do you want to add class while you make #tout fade out ?